# requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS

Tags: ajax, wcf

I am making an ajax call from Sharepoint site to access data from a public facing website.

```
 $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
    url: 'http://license.mypublicfacingwebsite.com/my.svc/productValidation/https%E2%82%ACMYSPSITE.sharepoint.com,123AppName,15',  
    success: function (data) {  
        $($.parseJSON(data.d)).each(function (index, value) {  

        });  
    },  
    error: function (result) {  
        alert(result);  
    }  
});
```

I get the error of

> "requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   http://license.mypublicfacingwebsite.com/my.svc/productValidation/https%E2%82%ACMYSPSITE.sharepoint.com,123AppName,15".This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

What should I do in order to make this WCF call work.?

Comment: Call it via HTTPS.